# problem using sql instead of named scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have a method "search" in my model, which depending upon the various parameters passed runs an sql query in which i am joining seven tables. but when i am using this method with another named scope then error is shown "undefined method call for array".

but when instead of this search method if i use group of named scope then it works fine.
so how to integrate named scope with that method

Comment: it would help if you showed some code

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell for sure without seeing the code.  But it sounds like the search method is intended to be called on the Model class and when you chain the named_scope calls either they don't know what to do with the array your search method supplies or your search method doesn't know what to do with the array of records the names scope supplies.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `#search` method is probably returning something (an `Array`?) that does not implement some method that `named_scope` expects. From a quick look into `activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb` it appears that `named_scope` returns a `Scope` object, which does implement `#call` (and a bunch of other non-Array methods too). That looks to be why chaining scopes works. So an Array just isn't going to work.

Could you rework your `#search` method into a `named_scope`? I realise that you're going to get an unusually (for me, at least) complex definition, but you should then be able to chain your results with other scopes.

Alternatively, how about making your custom search method work so that it returns (and must also take, for chaining before and after to work) a Scope? Probably haarder to do than a big named_scope though.

Answer (score 0):

hey sorry for replying late, but found the answer
I have stored the query in a variable and then passed to the named scope where i do find_by_sql.
hence got the desired result.